# Simplifying a fraction with bringing in new variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Let's say I have a fraction like this:

```
(a b x^2 + a^3 x) / (a^2 b x)
```

and I would like to simplify it by multiplying both the numerator and the denominator with

```
1/x^4
```

while introducing the following:

```
a/x = A and b/x = B
```

So in the end I'd get:

```
(A B + A^3) / (A^2 B)
```

Is there a way to do this in Mathematica?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid potential naming conflicts, you should avoid using capital letters to start user-defined variables/functions (e.g., A and B). In the desired result a factor of A can be cancelled.

```
(a b x^2 + a^3 x)/(a^2 b x) /. {a -> A*x, b -> B*x} // Simplify // Together
```

> (A^2 + B)/(A*B)